# I want to make weblogic startupclass as singletonservice

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

In `weblogic` we have **startup class**  which implements `T3StartupDef` interface
and I want to implement the same class as `SingletonService`. But there is two different methods from two different interface. startup() & activate().
In `startup()` we are going to read same property file argument.
How we will add same code in two methods startup() & activate() method.

I have question How I make my startup class as singletonservice.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In weblogic API implementation we need not required to call `activate()` manually. So I removed `T3StartupDef` interface implementation and instead of that I added `SingletonService` interface implementation. And the code which is in the `startup()` is copied to `activate()` and make sure all the resource should be available in class-path. We need to required to initiate 
`activate()` manually it called automatically while our application was deployed. This is managed by weblogic itself you need config those parameter in `weblogic-application,xml` & from weblogic admin console also.
For more detail implementation [please click here.](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=3773)